# NoReverseMatch at /signup/

Tags: python, django

```
Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': b'Mw', 'token': '4vb-698f794fd74543e1258f'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']
```

templates/account_activation_email.html

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},

Please click on the link below to confirm your registration:

http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

It seems to be working fine on my localhost url; but when it's deplyed in heroku. it throws this error.

views.py

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.profile.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account_activation_invalid.html')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        core_views.activate, name='activate'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'uidb64': b'Mw'
```

this is a `byte code`, but `django` expects a `string`,

so in the `view` from where you are sending the `uid`

do a `decode`, `uid.decode('utf-8')`

then send it to the template

Comment: Worked! You're a life saver.